# Excel variable in formule

Tags: excel

I currently have this problem.
I have this forumule:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("H11:H"&M11)).
```

But i would like to make the first one a variable. So, I tried:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("H"&M12":H"))
```

However this didn't work, is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a column AND a row reference for both parts of the range.

So, if your end formula is something like `=Sum(H20:H44)` and the two numbers for the row references live in cells M11 and M12, then you need to tie **BOTH** these cells into the Indirect text. Also remember that you need to concatenate **ALL** elements with the `&` character, like this:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("H"&M12&":H"&M11))
```

In words: use the text `H`, then concatenate the number you find in M12, then concatenate the text `:H`, then concatenate the text you find in M11. Turn that into a range and sum the values.

Answer (score 0):

Or again, to avoid the use of Volatile INDIRECT, use INDEX:

```
=SUM(INDEX(H:H,M12):INDEX(H:H,M11))
```

You can relace either the INDEX with a set cell address

```
=SUM(INDEX(H:H,M12):H1048576)
```

This will sum everything from the row depicted by M12 and the the rest of the column H.